# How to create a dictionary of rectangles from xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dictionary

I have many rectangles in xaml and I want to make a dictionary collection of them, is it even possible?

```
Dictionary<int, object> rectangles = new Dictionary<int, object>(9);
   {
      rectangles.Add(1, rectangle1);
   }
```

Here is the XAML

```
<WrapPanel x:Name="HelmetPanel" Style="{StaticResource Panel}" > 
    <Rectangle x:Name="helmet_rectangle1" Fill="Aqua" 
               Style="{StaticResource Rectanglestyle}"
               MouseDown="helmet_rectangle1_MouseDown_1" 
               DragEnter="helmet_rectangle1_DragEnter_1" 
               DragLeave="helmet_rectangle1_DragLeave_1" 
               MouseLeftButtonDown="helmet_rectangle1_MouseLeftButtonDown_1"
               PreviewDrop="helmet_rectangle1_PreviewDrop_1" /> 
</WrapPanel>
```

Comment: can you show the xaml? (the relevant pieces)

Comment: If this code is in your code behind you could just do `Dictionary<int, object> rectangles = new Dictionary<int, object>(9);
   {
      rectangles.Add(1, helmet_rectangle1);
   }` But you actually really shouldn't use your UI elements as objects. maybe you should make a class that represents such a rectangle and use that

Comment: @StijnvanGaal I thought about a class that represents rectangles but it's a last resort. But i can't use Add(1, helmet_rectangle1) because it's beyound visibiity scope even if i write using /name of my project/

Comment: why dont you create a binding source in the XAML and pass the value into a list view....

Comment: I can't see the reason why you would want to do this - IMO there is very seldom a reason to keep track of your UI elements, unless you are creating a new UserControl where you want to control some of its sub elements. But even then it is rarely used. I would rather use DataTemplates and bindings to control the UI. With that said, could you add the reason why you would want to do this? Maybe there are better solutions which will be more maintainable and more easily understood.

Comment: Why can't you just bind the collection to an `ItemsControl` where the `ItemsPanelTemplate` is set to a `WrapPanel`?

Comment: Did you managed to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate the controls in your window. Then match the `x:Name` property.

```
var rectangles = new Dictionary<int, Rectangle>();
var index = 0;
for(var control in HelmetPanel.Children
                              .Where(c => c.Name != null && 
                                          c.Name.StartsWith("helmet_rectangle")
                              .OrderBy(c => c.Name))
{
     rectangles.Add(index++, control as Rectangle)
}
```

I am not in the position to check this code, so it might have some issues, but this is basically a way that will work.

Having said this, it might be interesting to know why you need this dictionary since it seems that there are better ways to accomplish what you want to do. Possible XY problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: But such objects like HelmetPanel and helmet_rectangle1 are invisible, what shoul i do to use them? 
Unf i have to accomplish this in only one way - using dictionaries of rectangles, as I described

Comment: Invisible? How exactly? There is no `Visibility` tag in your XAML. Nevertheless the controls are added to the wrappanel and have a unique name to identify them, so you would be able to see them in the `Children` collection.